# Is Avogadro's number an integer?

Tags: mole

I have heard that [Avogadro's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant), $N_\mathrm A=6.022 \times 10^{23}$, is the number of atoms contained in $12$ grams of $\ce{^{12}C}$. I think it should be an integer, but I couldn't find the exact number. Is it an integer?

Comment: There is ***no*** exact value. The value with something like a dozen decimal digits you might have seen in a textbook is as exact as it gets.

Comment: It is nonetheless an integer, for sure. You can't have half an atom.

Comment: @FelipeS.S.Schneider You're assuming that 12 g is such that an integral number of carbon-12 atoms go into it?

Comment: The old (1971 I guess) definition of mole that you stated surely leads to floating point numbers (although only if you measure weights with more than 23 significant digits). The [new definition](https://iupac.org/new-definition-mole-arrived/) (2018) fixes one mole to be exactly $6.02214076 \times 10^{23}$, which is an integer.

Comment: I stand corrected. As @Felipe says, since very recently there **is** an exact value, and (not that it is of any slightest importance) it is an integer.

Comment: @orthocresol Yes, since I wasn’t absolutely sure whether the question is really about Avogadro’s number or actually about the Avogadro constant

Comment: @Felipe to reduce confusion could you turn your observation into an amswer?

Comment: Ok, I'll do it in the other question (sorry for being late!).